# Example of a set closed under consequence but not maximally consistent

Tags: logic

A set $\Gamma$ of propositional formulas is closed under derivations if, for any $\varphi$, we have $\Gamma \vdash
\varphi \Rightarrow \varphi \in \Gamma$.

A set is maximally consistent if it is
consistent and for any $\Gamma'$ s.t. $\Gamma \subseteq \Gamma'$ and $\Gamma'$
consistent, then $\Gamma ' = \Gamma$ (i.e. there is no larger set of
propositions that is consistent.)

Every maximally consistent set is closed under derivations (or closed under consequence). I am trying to determine if the reverse is true. My intuition is that it is not; i.e., that there are sets cloesd under derivations that are not maximally consistent. However, I haven't been able to find an example of such set.

A particular problem is that the counterexample I'm looking for must be infinite. Any finite set $\{\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n \}$ of arbitrary size $n$ is *not* closed under derivation. (It is easy to imagine infinite combinations, using the connectives $\land, \lor,$ etc, of the elements of the set, which a finite set could never contain).

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:** Let the set of sentence symbols be a singleton set $S=\{p\}$, and let $\Gamma$ be the set of tautologies, i.e. the "closure under derivations" of the empty set.

1. Can you see why $\Gamma$ is closed under derivations?
2. Can you see why the sentence $\varphi = p$ is not in $\Gamma$?
3. Can you see why the sentence $\varphi = p$ is *consistent* with $\Gamma$?

Comment: The answer given above is very good. Another obvious counterexample (the dual, if you will) that comes to mind is *the set of all formulas*. It is closed under consequence, albeit trivially since the consequent (of he definition of closure under derivation) is always satisfied, but it is not consistent, so *a fortiori* not maximally consistent.

Comment: Thanks again Franklin

Comment: @lafinur Sure thing ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by Franklin Pezzuti Dyer is very good. Another obvious counterexample (the dual, if you will) that comes to mind is the *set of all formulas*. It is closed under consequence, albeit trivially since the consequent (of the definition of closure under derivation) is always satisfied, but it is not consistent, so *a fortiori* not maximally consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already provided nice examples. Let me add a few more.
Assume $p,q$ are two distinct propositional symbols, and define
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma_0 &= \{ \varphi :\ \vdash \varphi\} \\
\Gamma_1 &= \{ \varphi :\ p\lor q\vdash \varphi\} \\
\Gamma_2 &= \{ \varphi :\ p\vdash \varphi\} \\
\Gamma_3 &= \{ \varphi :\ p\land q\vdash \varphi\} \\
\end{align}
$$

All the sets above are closed under consequence, by construction.

It is easy to verify that we have the strict inclusions $\Gamma_0\subset\Gamma_1 \subset \Gamma_2 \subset \Gamma_3$, so this proves that  all of these sets (except the last $\Gamma_3$) are not maximal.

Following the same idea, whenever you have a sequence of stronger and stronger formulas, you can make a chain of strictly increasing closed under consequence sets.

You can even find families of sets not forming a chain. Above you can also add $\Gamma_2' = \{ \varphi :\ q\vdash \varphi\}$ which is incomparable to $\Gamma_2$ but in the same order relationship to other sets $\Gamma_i$.